# Joining two lists with unequal number of elements into a dictionary

Tags: python

so lets say I have two lists, one with the names of directors and the other with the name of movies.

So:

```
directors = ['Tarr', 'Lynch' 'Coen']
movies = ['movie1', 'movie2', 'movie3', 'movie4']
```

End result I want:

```
{'movie1':'Tarr', 'movie2':'Tarr', 'movie3':'Lynch', 'movie4':'Tarr'}
```

But wait a minute? What about Coen? The other thing I want is that the value (director) to be randomly selected.

The part I'm really having trouble with is forcing the dictionary to show 4 elements. Python is only giving me 3 since the `directors` list only contains 3 directors even though there are 4 movies.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
from random import choice

results = {}
for movie in movies:
    results[movie] = choice(directors)
```

This will choose a random director for each movie in the movies list, and store them in a results dictionary.

You could do the same thing with a dictionary comprehension:

```
from random import choice

results = {x: choice(directors) for x in movies}
```

Comment: Wow that is super pythonic. Props for making it seem so simple.

Comment: No worries! Added an edit that may be even more Pythonic ;) if this answer helped you, please feel free to accept it as correct.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to tell us if you are choosing with replacement or not. Anyway I hope this helps (this is with replacement):

```
import random

directors = ['Tarr', 'Lynch' 'Coen']
movies = ['movie1', 'movie2', 'movie3', 'movie4']
my_dictionary = {}
for each_movie in movies:
    my_dictionary[each_movie] = random.choice(directors)
print my_dictionary
```

Comment: Good point, but if it was choice _without_ replacement, bLunt would still have the problem of too few directors for too many movies, so I doubt that's what he or she could have wanted or meant.

Answer (score 2):

To make [Ben's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30280965/674064) even more pythonic, use a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) (available in Python ≥ 2.7):

```
import random

directors = ['Tarr', 'Lynch' 'Coen']
movies = ['movie1', 'movie2', 'movie3', 'movie4']

results = { movie : random.choice(directors) for movie in movies }
```

(I like to simply `import random` instead of `from random import choice`, so I can refer to `random.choice` by its fully qualified name and thus get code that's telling the reader that it's performing a **random** choice.)